# Can a cubic equation be turned into a system of simultaneous equations in three unknowns?

Tags: polynomials

Whilst trying to understand the role of symmetric polynomial s in Galois' Theory I managed to solve a quadratic equation by converting it into a system of simultaneous equations in two unknowns.

I proceeded as follows:

Suppose you have $ax^2+bx+c=0$ whose roots are $\alpha$ and   $\beta$ then $\alpha +\beta=-\frac{b}{a}$ and $\alpha\beta=\frac{c}{a}$.

I realised that $(\alpha-\beta)^2=(\alpha+\beta)^2-4\alpha\beta$ and is a symmetric polynomial and so  I formed the system: $$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1 \\ 1& -1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{b}{a} \\ \sqrt{\frac{b^2}{a^2} -\frac{4c}{a}}\end{bmatrix}$$  The matrix of coefficients is nonsingular and so the solution will depend on the existence of the discriminant quantity as usual.

**Can a cubic equation be likewise converted to a system of equations?**

In researching I found out the usual way to solve a cubic is to transform it into a depressed cubic. As I understand things this transform is designed to make the sum of roots zero. This leads me to believe the answer to my question is no.  Clearly there is no general formula for the general quintic polynomial so I believe the setting up of formulas must fail at some stage.

Thanks for considering the question.

Comment: Got it thanks @LeeMosher

Comment: try to use Vieta's formulas. I think they would be helpful in constructing the raltions between the terms as you did for quadratic equation.

Comment: Did you mean _linear_ equations maybe?

Comment: @dxiv that's what I thought initially but then why depress the cubic? I then though perhaps a system in other powers of the roots.  Will linear equations fail as I'd assumed?

Comment: @Jane vieta was the original inspiration. Is it possible for the cubic case?

Comment: You won't find a system of linear equations in the general case. But if you drop the linearity, then you'll find _many_ possible systems. Vieta's formulas, for example (as mentioned by @Jane already). Or let $x_k = x^k$ and write the obvious $n$ equations. Whether any of those systems would be easier to solve than the original equation itself is another story, however.